# Thinkpad X41 Tablet Wacom stylus stopped working on Lubuntu 14.10

Tags: lubuntu, thinkpad, tablet, wacom, 14.10

I've just upgraded to lubuntu 14.10 from an old release on my thinkpad x41 tablet, and the wacom stylus device appears to be lost. `xinput --list` used to yield `Serial Wacom Tablet stylus` as a pointer device, but now nothing other than the trackpoint is recognized. `xsetwacom list` returns nothing.

`xserver-xorg-input-wacom` is already installed on the system, with no `wacom-tools` available in the default repos. So far I've tried `modprobe wacom` and `modprobe wacom_w8001` (the stylus/tablet is a w8001 serial device), neither would pick up the stylus; among others that returns `can't set device type`, `inputattach --w8001 /dev/ttyS4` keeps getting timeouts.

I'm at a loss here, presumably the stylus would work with unity ubuntu, which however would be far too heavy for the x41.

Comment: Found a workaround here (but for my lenovo X41 / lubuntu it did not work): [https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xf86-input-wacom/+bug/1392887](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xf86-input-wacom/+bug/1392887) I wait for the official bugfix.

Comment: This is a bug. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xf86-input-wacom/+bug/1392887

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it to work with the following workaround:

I just removed the whole folder /lib/udev/rules.d/69-wacom.rules/
(Actually I moved it to my Desktop just in case I need it again.)

Then I added the following file (named 69-xserver-xorg-input-wacom.rules) instead of the removed folder (I have copied the file from the ubuntu installed on my lenovo X61 Tablet):

/lib/udev/rules.d/69-xserver-xorg-input-wacom.rules

```
# udev rules for wacom tablets.
# These rules were compiled for the Debian GNU/Linux distribution,
# but others may, and indeed are encouraged to, use them also.
#
# Should you do so, PLEASE CO-ORDINATE ANY CHANGES OR ADDITIONS
# of new devices with Ron <ron@debian.org> so that we can try
# to present users with a standard set of device nodes which
# they can rely on across the board.

# Catch the serial tablets and tell X that's what they are
ACTION=="add|change", SUBSYSTEM=="pnp", ATTR{id}=="WACf*", ENV{NAME}="Serial Wacom Tablet"
ACTION=="add|change", SUBSYSTEM=="pnp", ATTR{id}=="FUJ*", ENV{NAME}="Serial Wacom Tablet"
ACTION=="add|change", SUBSYSTEMS=="pnp", ATTRS{id}=="WACf*", ENV{ID_INPUT}="1", ENV{ID_INPUT_TABLET}="1"
ACTION=="add|change", SUBSYSTEMS=="pnp", ATTRS{id}=="FUJ*", ENV{ID_INPUT}="1", ENV{ID_INPUT_TABLET}="1"

KERNEL!="event[0-9]*", GOTO="wacom_end"

# Port specific link for users of multiple tablets of the same type.
# The ID_PATH variable is set by the "path_id" script in an earlier rule file.
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ENV{ID_PATH}=="?*", SYMLINK="input/by-path/$env{ID_PATH}-wacom"

# Multiple interface support for stylus and touch devices.
DRIVERS=="wacom", ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00", ENV{WACOM_TYPE}="stylus"
DRIVERS=="wacom", ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="01", ENV{WACOM_TYPE}="touch"

# Type-named links for multiple tablets.  If you want to use multiple
# tablets of the _same_ type, you will probably need to use the links
# from /dev/input/by-path to identify which is plugged into what usb
# port.  For different tablet types though, just pick your links from
# the list below.
#
# We override SYMLINK for tabletpc devices because the by-path link
# is not required with such devices, there will only ever be one.
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0000", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-penpartner"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0003", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-cintiq_partner"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0010", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-graphire"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0011", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-graphire2-4x5"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0012", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-graphire2-5x7"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0013", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-graphire3"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0014", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-graphire3-6x8"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0015", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-graphire4-4x5"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0016", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-graphire4-6x8"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0017", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-bamboofun-4x5"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0018", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-bamboofun-6x8"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0019", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-bamboo1-medium"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0020", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos-4x5"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0021", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos-6x8"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0022", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos-9x12"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0023", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos-12x12"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0024", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos-12x18"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0030", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-pl400"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0031", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-pl500"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0032", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-pl600"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0033", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-pl600sx"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0034", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-pl550"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0035", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-pl800"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0037", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-pl700"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0038", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-pl510"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0039", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-dtu710"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="003f", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-cintiq21ux"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0041", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos2-4x5"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0042", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos2-6x8"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0043", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos2-9x12"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0044", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos2-12x12"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0045", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos2-12x18"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0047", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos2-6x8a"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0060", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-volito"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0061", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-penstation2"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0062", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-volito2-4x5"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0063", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-volito2-2x3"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0064", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-penpartner2"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0065", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-bamboo"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0069", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-bamboo1"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0081", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-graphire_bt-6x8"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0090",  SYMLINK="input/tablet-tpc90"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0093",  SYMLINK="input/tablet-tpc93-$env{WACOM_TYPE}"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="009a",  SYMLINK="input/tablet-tpc9a-$env{WACOM_TYPE}"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00b0", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos3-4x5"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00b1", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos3-6x8"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00b2", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos3-9x12"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00b3", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos3-12x12"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00b4", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos3-12x19"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00b5", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos3-6x11"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00b7", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos3-4x6"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00b8", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos4-4x6"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00b9", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos4-6x9"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00ba", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos4-8x13"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00bb", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos4-12x19"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00c0", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-dtf521"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00c4", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-dtf720"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00c5", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-cintiq20wsx"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00c6", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-cintiq12wx"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00c7", ENV{WACOM_TYPE}!="touch", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-dtu1931"

# Convenience links for the common case of a single tablet.  We could do just this:
#ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", SYMLINK+="input/wacom-$env{WACOM_TYPE}"
# but for legacy reasons, we keep the input/wacom link as the generic stylus device.
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ENV{WACOM_TYPE}!="touch", SYMLINK+="input/wacom"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ENV{WACOM_TYPE}=="touch", SYMLINK+="input/wacom-touch"

# Check and repossess the device if a module other than the wacom one
# is already bound to it.
#
# We probably don't need this one in the Real World anymore ...
# See the old wacom-tools package if we actually do need to resurrect the
# check_driver script for this again.
#ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ACTION=="add", RUN+="check_driver wacom $devpath $env{ID_BUS}"

LABEL="wacom_end"
```

Comment: This also worked on a Motion LE 1700 Tablet PC with the same symptoms.

Comment: This also works for lenovo Tablet X201 (I think, it works for all lenovo Tablets).