# Serial device not detected by Lubuntu

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, input-devices, serial-port, xinput

`Serial Wacom Tablet stylus` and `Serial Wacom Tablet eraser` [should appear in the xinput list](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217121) in a [Motion LE 1700](http://www.pcworld.com/product/1372076/motion-le1700-tablet-pc.html), however they are missing in Lubuntu 14 (32bit).

Is there a way to make Lubuntu discover these devices?

Note: Linux Mint and Elementary OS recognize these devices right out the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by recreating an older Ubuntu file  `69-xserver-xorg-input-wacom.rules` in  `/lib/udev/rules.d/69-wacom.rules/` thanks to [Phi](https://askubuntu.com/a/558051/371709) at AskUbuntu.com

The Stylus pen and eraser are detected in the xinput list and both have pressure sensitivity.

The code is posted [in this response](https://askubuntu.com/a/558051/371709) and is also found in older Ubuntu/Lubuntu versions.